# add a check with MessageBox when DataGrid is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a desktop app already released (so I'd appreciate an answer that keeps the changes and regression tests at a minimum) and I need to add a consistency check `CanBeDeleted` when the grid is changed.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPosIn.PosInLocationsList}" 
    CanUserAddRows="{Binding UpdateEnabled}" CanUserDeleteRows="{Binding UpdateEnabled}" >
```

I'm using `UpdateEnabled` for something different (profile permissions) and I don't want to make the `DataGrid` read only either: I'd prefer  (*unless it is too complex*)  to see a blocking alert (a `MessageBox`) preventing changes.

What I've done till now is

1. against MVVM, because I've put the alert in the Model (but I can accept this, if it makes the changes quick and simple)
2. not working, because the second part (see below) of my changes produces an invalid operation exception

The ViewModel contains the following list

```
    [Association(ThisKey="Partita", OtherKey="Partita", CanBeNull=true, IsBackReference=true)]
    public ObservableCollection<Model.PosInLocation> posin_locations_list = new  ObservableCollection<Model.PosInLocation>(); 
    public ObservableCollection<PosInLocation> PosInLocationsList {
        get { return posin_locations_list; }
        set { 
            posin_locations_list = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( () => PosInLocationsList );
        }
    }
```

and I'm adding the consistency check here

```
    string _storage;
    [Column(Name = "storage"), PrimaryKey]
    public string Storage {
        get { return _storage; }
        set { 
            if (this.loadedEF) {
                string validate_msg;
                if (!PurchasePosIn.CanBeDeleted(out validate_msg)) {
                    // against MVVM
                    MessageBox.Show(validate_msg, "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK); 
                    OnPropertyChanged( () => Storage  );
                    return;
                }
                Persistence.MyContext.deletePosInLocation(this);
            }
            _storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( () => Storage  );
            if (this.loadedEF) {
                Persistence.MyContext.insertPosInLocation(this);
            }               
        }
    }
```

and here (second part)

```
    internal void posin_locations_list_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {                   
        string validate_msg;
        if (!CanBeDeleted(out validate_msg)) {
            // indirectly produces an invalid operation exception 
            MessageBox.Show(validate_msg, "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return;
        }
        if (args.OldItems != null)
            foreach(var oldItem in args.OldItems) {
                if ( ((PosInLocation)oldItem).Partita != null)        
                    Persistence.MyContext.deletePosInLocation((PosInLocation)oldItem);              
            }       
        if (args.NewItems != null)
            foreach(var newItem in args.NewItems)
            {
                PosInLocation newPosInLocation = (PosInLocation)newItem;
                if ( newPosInLocation.Partita == null) {
                    newPosInLocation.Partita = this.Partita;
                    newPosInLocation.PurchasePosIn = this;
                    newPosInLocation.loadedEF = true;
                }
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the ObservableCollection implemented a "previewCollectionChanged", things would be so much easier.
For your needs I would recommend creating a subclass of ObservableCollection and overloading the protected method RemoveItem.
Depending on what you are doing with your application, you might want to override other methods than just RemoveItem (like ClearItems).
When subclassing ObservableCollection, there are 5 protected methods you can override : ClearItems, RemoveItem, InsertItem, SetItem and MoveItem. 
These methods are, in the end, called by all the public methods, so overriding them gives you full control.

Here's a small app you can run that demonstrates this :

### ObservableCollection SubClass

```
public class ObservableCollectionWithDeletionControl<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public delegate void DeletionDeniedEventHandler(object sender, int indexOfDeniedDeletion);
    public event DeletionDeniedEventHandler DeletionDenied;

    public bool CanDelete { get; set; }

    protected virtual void OnDeletionDenied(int indexOfDeniedDeletion)
    {
        if (DeletionDenied != null) { DeletionDenied(this, indexOfDeniedDeletion); }
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        if (CanDelete)
        {
            base.RemoveItem(index);
        }
        else
        {
            OnDeletionDenied(index);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the DeletionDenied event so that this class is not responsible for showing the error window, and it makes it more reusable.

### ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindow window { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollectionWithDeletionControl<Person> People { get; set; } = new ObservableCollectionWithDeletionControl<Person>();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People.DeletionDenied += People_DeletionDenied;
    }

    private void People_DeletionDenied(object sender, int indexOfDeniedDeletion)
    {
        Person personSavedFromDeletion = People[indexOfDeniedDeletion];
        window.displayDeniedDeletion(personSavedFromDeletion.Name);
    }
}
```

The ViewModel for the MainWindow.
It knows it's window for the sole purpose of displaying the error message.
 *(I'm sure there's a better solution than this out there but I have yet to find a good and short way of displaying popup windows in mvvm.)*
When the DeletionDenied event triggers, the error window is called.

### Model

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if(_name == value) { return; }
            _name = value;
            if( PropertyChanged != null ) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); }
        }
    }

    private string _name = "";
}
```

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Can delete" IsChecked="{Binding People.CanDelete}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Margin="5,0"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

### XAML.CS

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void displayDeniedDeletion(string name)
    {
        TextBox errorMessage = new TextBox();
        errorMessage.Text = string.Format("Cannot delete {0} : access denied !", name);

        Window popupErrorMessage = new Window();
        popupErrorMessage.Content = errorMessage;

        popupErrorMessage.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

### APP MAIN

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        MainWindowViewModel viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

        viewModel.window = window;
        window.DataContext = viewModel;
        window.Show();

        App.Current.MainWindow = window;
    }
}
```

I've set the ViewModel's window in the startup, but you should probably do it wherever you create your ViewModel

Comment: @user1892538 I updated my post with an example. Would this work with your application?

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I want to underline 2 things 1) to make it more reusable, besides the DeletionDenied event, I should define also a CanDelete (similarly other 2 for insert) so that this class is not responsible for the condition logic. 2) "*I have yet to find a good and short way of displaying popup windows in mvvm.*" although I accept your answer for subclassing and events, this part is too rough,  I agree that the ideal solution  (a dependency property) is not so easy and short... but why don't you like the approach in the first part of my answer? I'll stick with it, to be blunt.

Comment: @user1892538 1) I did define a CanDelete in my class, or did you have something else in mind ? 2) Ah, I was not aware that the MessageBox class was a standard class. Yes using this is much less "rough" than what I did (I'll try to update my answer later), but it's basically the same thing. The reason why I don't like this solution is because it breaks the MVVM pattern, the ViewModel must know the Window (or in your case MessageBox) class in order to function, which should only belong in the View. A cleaner approach would probably be using an interface between VM and the user information logic.

Comment: Hi! regarding point 2) I'm not suggesting to use the `MessageBox` like i did in my question, but a *standard, mvvm string property* with a *binding* to a `TextBox` (or more elegant a dp), triggering the `MessageBox` *in the xaml*: I think this is completely correct from a mvvm perspective, isn't it? ... by the way, your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` is wrong (I know it's irrelevant but better not showing it) Finally point 1) maybe you are right (I had in mind another event handler), I will double check this point

Comment: @user1892538 Ok, I understand what you are proposing regarding the Message box and yes, I think that would be an ideal solution. I haven't played too much with DependencyPropertuies, I'll give it a shot in the future. *"your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged is wrong"*, are you refering to the fact that I forgot to check if it's null? Thanks for pointing it out, I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's ugly (really, it's not so ugly: imho it's a nice [MVVM approach](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/317049/mvvm-approach-to-mahapps-metro-dialogs), also applicable to modern [mahapps.metro](http://mahapps.com/) `Dialogs`), but now I'm setting

```
if (!CanBeDeleted(out validate_msg)) {
    PurchaseItem.MessageBoxText = validate_msg;
```

an invisible `TextBox`

```
    <TextBox Visibility="Hidden" Name="tb_message"
        Text="{Binding MessageBoxText}"
        TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
```

where I'm dispatching the alert

```
    void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string alert = tb_message.Text;
        if (alert != null && tb_message.Text.Length>0) {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                (Action)(() => { 
                            MessageBox.Show(alert, "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                            tb_message.Text = "";
                         }));
        }
    }
```

### Rolling back added/deleted items

I see a connection with this other question [Prevent adding the new Item on ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794217/prevent-adding-the-new-item-on-observablecollection-collectionchanged-event), in my case I'd say that prevent deleting is even more important. I don't know if there are more updated answers than this one ([Can I rollback collection changes on collection changed event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530893/6996876) which appears [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530843/can-i-rollback-collection-changes-on-collection-changed-event/4530893#comment12552592_4530893)) about this topic.

While the `PropertyChanged` can be easily raised to rollback an item update, for the collection changes I've been forced to pass and reference the view dispatcher inside the `CollectionChanged` event

```
PurchaseItem.dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => RollBack(args)));
```

to rollback the added/deleted items

```
    bool rollingBack = false;
    private void RollBack(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) {
            rollingBack = true;
            if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (var element in args.OldItems) {
                    PosInLocationsList.Add((PosInLocation)element);
                }
            }
            if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (var element in args.NewItems) {
                    PosInLocationsList.Remove((PosInLocation)element);
                }
            }
            rollingBack = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I've done till now is
>
> against MVVM, because I've put the alert in the Model

The solution from @Tesseract, subclassing `ObservableCollection` and subscribing `RemoveItem` is already MVVM oriented.

What is still missing is a correct, modern way to send the alert from the ViewModel. This is where [Mahapps approach](https://dragablz.net/2015/05/29/using-mahapps-dialog-boxes-in-a-mvvm-setup/) would be helpful.

- Use an attached property in your Window to register your view model
  with the dialog sub-system.

In your XAML

```
Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
```

where the attached property [DialogPartecipation](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro.Shared/Controls/Dialogs/DialogParticipation.cs) will keep track of the views through a dictionary

```
public static class DialogParticipation
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<object, DependencyObject> ContextRegistrationIndex = new Dictionary<object, DependencyObject
```

- You can instantiate DialogCoordinator directly or inject the
  interface IDialogCoordinator into their view model

The [DialogCoordinator](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro.Shared/Controls/Dialogs/DialogCoordinator.cs) will match the ViewModel to the View

```
public class DialogCoordinator : IDialogCoordinator
{
    public static readonly IDialogCoordinator Instance = new DialogCoordinator();
```

through the above said attached property (the `context` being the view model)

```
var association = DialogParticipation.GetAssociation(context);
```

and display the dialog, invoking the appropriate method on the retrieved view: this is how, if you have multiple windows open, the dialog will display on the correct window.